# Solving a Min-Max Optimization Problem with Constraint

Tags: optimization, minmax

I'm trying to solve the following optimization problem:

min max{x + 2y − 1, 2x + 0.5y + 0.75}
s.t. x + y = 1,

so far i've tried to solve it separately in terms of max and min but im not sure when i can use the constrain, can i solve it  as :
max{x + 2y − 1, 2x + 0.5y + 0.75}
s.t x+y=1
and then taking the min value

or

finding the max value and then solve the problem under the constrain that x+y=1

Additionally, in the total case i  would like to know if max min(f,g,...,h)) equals to any function.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This doesn't appear to be a programming question and is therefore _off-topic_.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret this, and formulate this as:

```
  min z
      z >= x + 2y − 1
      z >= 2x + 0.5y + 0.75
      x + y = 1 
      x,y >= 0 (???)
```

Comment: any other ideas? i don't wanna solve it using linear programing

Comment: Sorry, no. I tend to prefer to solve LP problems with LP solvers.